# How to reconnect Pubnub after internet reconnect in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I have a Pubnub instance,
I want to know how to handle reconnection when internet does down and comes back up with like a given number of retries? The documentation definitely gives the appropriate [docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-network-lifecycle) but I am unable to put it into code.

Help would be greatly appreciated.
my code:

```
this.pubnub = new PubNub({
  subscribeKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.subscribeKey,
  authKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.authKey,
  uuid,
  restore: true,
  ssl: true
});

this.listeners = {
  message: msgEvent => {
    console.log(msgEvent);
  },
  status: statusEvent => {

  }
};

this.pubnub.addListener(this.listeners);
```

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064086/how-to-reconnect-in-pubnub

Answer (score 2):

Set `restore:true` in your init code.

```js
this.pubnub = new PubNub({
  subscribeKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.subscribeKey,
  authKey: this.serverDetails.authInfo.authKey,
  uuid,
  ssl: true,
  restore: true // this allows reconnect to restore your channel subscription
});
```

Comment: We are improving the docs so that all of this is very clear. First update later this month.

Comment: so you're saying, this.pubnub.reconnect() will reconnect but to restore channel subscription I must add restore: true in init? It's mot working for me.

Comment: Yes, `restore:true` tells the SDK to cache the channel list you are subscribed to before the disconnect so that `reconnect` can use that list. This will be improved in the forthcoming v5 SDK but that's a ways off so don't wait for that. If this is not working for you then let me know your PubNub JavaScript SDK version. Be sure you are on the latest one. There was a regression on this a few versions ago.

Comment: I don't see PNReconnectedCategory status coming after reconnect being called.

Comment: You will not get the Reconnected category. You should get a NetworkUp category. And I misled you a bit. When you do `restore:true` the `reconnect` is called for you. No need to call it manually. Well, that is what is supposed to happen. I just tested it last week and it worked for me. So maybe share a simple code example (complete example though) that I can run (redact your pub/sub keys) and/or [provide SDK logs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and we can troubleshoot.

Comment: You can just submit all the above to [PubNub Support for free](https://support.pubnub.com). Tell them Craig sent you in case I need to be involved with troubleshooting it and include link to this post so we can post back with any updated answers.

Comment: I won't be able to share complete code but that is literally the main part, there is only one channel that I am subscribed to. 

Initially:  PNConnectedCategory, 
disconnect wifi:  PNNetworkDownCategory, 
connect wifi:  PNNetworkUpCategory

Whats the use of reconnected category? how do I know if I'm connected again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211087/discussion-between-xaovnumwsercy-and-craig-conover).